# $('#id') returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

   <title>Pixgalery</title>

   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favbar.png" />

   <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/>
   <!-- JavaScript -->
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

            alert($('#fh'));

   </script>
   <script src="/stylesheets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <!-- CSS -->
   <link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
   media="screen">
   <link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <style type="text/css">

      body {

        <% if(user.background == ''){ %>

            background: rgb(241, 241, 241) url('/noise_filter.png');

        <% } else {%>

            background: url('.<%= user.paths %><%= user.background %>') fixed;

        <% } %>


       }

  </style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar-static-top navbar-inverse navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
   <div class="container">


  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </a>

  <a class="brand" href="#">Pixgalery</a>


  <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/<%= req %>">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>  
  <ul class="nav pull-left">
    <form class="navbar-search pull-left">
       <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search...">
    </form>
  </ul>


  </div>

 </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div style="margin-top: 15px;" class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span1"></div>
  <div class="span6">

  </div>
  </div>

<div class="span4">

    <aside>

         <center><h2 style="margin-top: 0px;"><%= photo.author %></h2></center>
         <table style="margin-top: 5px" class="table">
         <tbody style="background: white;">
            <tr>
              <td>
                    <h4>Views <small><%= photo.views %></small></h4>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
               <h4>Favourites <small><%= photo.fav %></small></h4>  
                    <button class="btn btn-inverse" id="fh">
                       <i style="margin-right: 5px;" class="icon-heart icon-white"></i>
                        Favorite</button> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
    </aside>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 </head>
</body>
```

When I get the alert `alert($('#fh'))`, the alert show me `[object Object]`, or even if I do `alert(document.getElementById('fh')`, I receive `null`, so, I can't interactive with that object with events such as `click()`. When I type in console `$('#fh')', I get the element, but I don't know why, for example this doesn't works:

```
  $('#fh').click(function(){

      alert('alert!');

  })
```

How can I resolve this...?

Thank's advance!

Comment: Nothing is wrong here. jQuery methods don't return exactly the same thing as vanilla DOM ones. Use `console.log()`, not `alert()`, for debugging.

Comment: Use `console.log()` for debugging, not alerts. As you see the string representation of an (jQuery) object is not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two problems at play here.

One, you are not using a document ready function from jQuery. The reason is, javascript is executed as it's found. When you call $("#fh") the element hasn't been downloaded from the server yet. **This is also why** your `document.getElementById(...)` call returns null, because *at the time of execution* that is correct.

Using a document ready method will wait till the document has been downloaded and parsed before executing the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Code here
});
```

Or

```
$(function() {
   // Code here
});
```

The other problem is you're confusing how jQuery works.

When you use the `$("#fh")` selector, it'll always return a jQuery object, even if it cannot find the element. the `[object Object]` output is just Firefox not knowing how to represent the object as a string.

You need to check the `.length` on a returned jQuery object to tell if there's actually something selected to register event handlers on.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have wrapped your code in a document.ready callback because at the moment you execute your code the DOM is not yet loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
         alert($('#fh'));
     });
</script>
```

But I would recommend you placing all your javascript files at the end of your DOM (for example jsu before the closing `</body>` tag) and not in the `<head>` section. This way you don't need to be wrapping them in a document.ready callback.

And as far as the `[Object] [Object]` is concerned, I would recommend you using a `console.log();` instead of `alert` to debug your javascript code.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code that tries to access elements in `document.ready`.  jQuery has built in methods to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

or even just

```
$(function  () {
```

***OR*** move your JavaScript to right before `</body>` to ensure that the rest of the DOM content is loaded.

`alert(document.getElementById('fh'))` is `null` because that element does not exist in the DOM when you try to get it at that point.  `$()` *always* returns a jQuery collection object even if the collection is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Start using jquery functions in `$(document).ready(function(){})...`. Only here you know that the page is fully loaded.
Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#fh').click(function(){
      alert('alert!');
   }) ;
}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before I begin I'm assuming that you want to print out the DOM element itself and not the text in the DOM element since you didn't say other wise.

Because technically you're returning a html dom element which the alert() function doesn't really no how to handle you can resolve this in one of two ways. The easiest way is

```
console.log($('#fh'));
```

which you can view in your browsers console which is located in it's debugger (hit ctr+shift+c in either firefox or chrome).